# How to get border Around <ul> tag?

Tags: html, css

My code is as follows :

```
<ul class="connected list no2">
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
  <li>Item 16</li>
</ul>
```

I want border around this `<ul>` tag

I tried as follows :

```
<div style="border:2px solid #a1a1a1;">
 <ul class="connected list no2">
      <li>Item 11</li>
      <li>Item 12</li>
      <li>Item 13</li>
      <li>Item 14</li>
      <li>Item 15</li>
      <li>Item 16</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

but it is showing div above the `<ul>`

Any suggestion on this please.

Comment: Just give that style to the `ul`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not just target the `ul` tag?

**CSS File:**

```
ul {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**Inline CSS:**

```
<ul class="connected list no2" style="border: 1px solid black">
```

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3s7J/) if you'd like to play with it.

Comment: fiddle is very helpful to understand css. One More if i want a header like something in the list what i supposed to do for this?

Comment: @SwapL You got it. If you want the header outside the box, just move the `h1` to before the `ul`.

Comment: @Beginner yes, i think i should go with your solution than my

Comment: @Beginner That works but why the extra hassle? Just make the `li` an `h1`. Thats why header tags exist.

Comment: @SwapL : you should use ElliotSchmelliot answer http://jsfiddle.net/s3s7J/1/ . That is better one

Comment: That was Swap's solution but yes I agree. That is the most correct solution here. Thanks for the extra help though Beginner.

Comment: ElliotSchmelliot and @Beginner your suggestions and solutions helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="connected">
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
  <li>Item 16</li>
</ul>

.connected
    {
       border: 1px solid #000;
       list-style-type: none;
    }
```

[`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/2NpLs/1/)

Comment: Apologies, your original code was targeting class `connected_list_no2` which did not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Jsbin  : http://jsbin.com/aQUteTO/1/

HTML :

```
<div style="border:2px solid #a1a1a1;">
    <ul class="connected list no2">
      <li>Item 11</li>
      <li>Item 12</li>
      <li>Item 13</li>
      <li>Item 14</li>
      <li>Item 15</li>
      <li>Item 16</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS  :

```
.connected{
  border:1px solid #FF0000
}
```

You can really avoid the Div as you just need to apply style to the corresponding class of `ul`.

So combined :

```
<ul class="connected list no2">
      <li>Item 11</li>
      <li>Item 12</li>
      <li>Item 13</li>
      <li>Item 14</li>
      <li>Item 15</li>
      <li>Item 16</li>
</ul>

.connected{
    border:1px solid #a1a1a1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of applying style to `div` tag, you can apply to `ul` tag

```
    <div>
    <ul class="connected list no2"  style="border:2px solid #a1a1a1;">
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>Item 12</li>
    <li>Item 13</li>
    <li>Item 14</li>
    <li>Item 15</li>
    <li>Item 16</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

OR, You can add css properties to any one of css class name you have added in ul tag already like `connected` `list` `no2`

```
.list{
  border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
}
```